# sessions are not getting stored in the browser cookies

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When i trying to run my API in postman it is working fine and sessions are getting maintained. But when i am trying to run it from UI Part the login session is not working.

This is my Login API from where i am login into

```
app.post('/user/login', (req, res, next) => {
        const body = req.body;
        let email = body.email;
        let password = body.password;
        const userDetails = db.collection(userProfiles);
        userDetails.findOne({email: email}, function (err, user) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            } else if (!user) {
                return res.status(400).send({
                    status: 'error',
                    message: 'user does not exist'
                });

            } else {
                if (user.password == password) {
                    user_object = user;
                    req.session.user = user;
                    return res.send({
                        user_obj: user,
                        status: 'success',
                        message: 'Successfully logged in'
                    });

                } else {
                    return res.status(400).send({
                        status: 'error',
                        message: 'Wrong Password'
                    })

                }
            }

            return res.send(user);
        });
    });
```

This is my session API from where i am sending user req.session.user on calling this api

````
app.get('/user/dashboard', function (req, res) {
        if (!req.session.user) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                data:'need to be logged in'
            });
        }
        return res.status(200).send({
            data:req.session.user
        });
    });```



The below is the javascript file from where i am trying to call the user stores in req.session.user

`
async function fetchUserId(){
    let cookie = document.cookie;
    let res = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8080/user/dashboard',
        {redirect: 'follow',
            headers:{
                "Cookie":cookie
            }});
    let userJson = await res.json();
    console.log(res);
    console.log(userJson);
    //return userJson;
};
`


when i hit the login API from Postman it is maintaining session and working fine but when i do the same from UI from browser it is giving error status 400 every time.
````

Answer (score 0):

You can do a

```
fetch(url, options).then(function(res) { console.log(res} )
```

and

```
app.get('/user/dashboard', function (req, res) {
        console.log(req.headers)
        if (!req.session.user) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                data:'need to be logged in'
            });
        }
        return res.status(200).send({
            data:req.session.user
        });
    });
```

To check is the cookie really there and where is the user object.

And you can check your browsers dev console to see if the cookie is updating.

I see that is fetch request you put a cookie in your header. But than at the API you are looking for a user at req.session.user. Although the cookie is in req.header["Cookie"].

Comment: So you are trying to say that cookie object is in req.headers . Due to which it is not able to fetch in browser cookie. Like in my case while running the api from postman it is working fine and the user sessions are also getting maintained. But the only problem came when trying to run through browser from the UI part .

Comment: console.log(req.headers);
it is not loggin anything

Comment: In that case just try to console.log(req)

Either you will be able to find your string/object there or you will know that there is no request coming into the API

Comment: Console.log(req) is not logging anything